# Crystal reports must compute a field only if it is greater than zero

Tags: crystal-reports

I created a report that compares two amounts and shows its increase or decrease percentage.

logic is

**amount1** compared to **amount2** then lastly show its **% inc/dec**

I have this field than computes for the increase/decrease of the number

formula is

```
(tonumber({tblReclass.Amount})/tonumber({tblReclass.AverageAmt}))*100-100
```

however there are data rows that contain zero values and zero division throws an error so I decided to put an if statement and the code is now this

```
if {tblReclass.Amount} > 0 and {tblReclass.AverageAmt} > 0 then

(tonumber({tblReclass.Amount})/tonumber({tblReclass.AverageAmt}))*100-100

else
 0
```

it now throws an error after the **then** statement it says

> a string is required here

what must be revised in the code

The computation works fine if I remove the zero values
so what I did temporarily was remove the zero data values but this report now shows incomplete data. I want to show the **zero values**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version:

```
if tonumber({tblReclass.AverageAmt}) > 0 then

(tonumber({tblReclass.Amount})/tonumber({tblReclass.AverageAmt}))*100-100

else 0
```

Comment: thank you very much, so I think my "if statement" considered the columns to be string so a tonumber is needed.